# Draw LED texture type text in Android

Tags: android, matrix

I want to covert my String for example:

```
{{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },{ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },{ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }};
```

In to integer 2 D-Matrix.I have tried but unable to complete it.Sometimes I get the following error.

> Array index Out Of Bound Exception

```
String[] rows = null;
try {
    rows = s.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println();
}

String[][] matrix = new String[rows.length][];
int r = 0;
for (String row : rows) {
    matrix[r++] = row.split("\\,");
}

System.out.println(matrix);
```

Comment: Is the length of the matrix fixed to 5 or it may vary?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for (String row : rows) {
    matrix[r++] = row.split("\\,");
}
```

You should have

```
for (String row : rows) {
    matrix[r] = row.split("\\,");
    r++;
}
```

I would imagine your matrix array starts from 0, but when you are using r++ you are putting the first entry into position 1 instead of 0 thus causing an out of range error later on when inserting the final string into the array.